# How to bypass event.stopPropagation to fire event

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to fire an event when I click on a like button.
My like button is generated with a plugin (WP ulike).

Problem : I can fire an event for a click everywhere on my div except on my button.  I did some research and saw that event.stopPropagation() could make this happened.

I check on the WP ulike plugin files and saw this:

```
_initLike: function(event) {
// Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases
event.stopPropagation();
```

Is there a way to bypass this without modifying the plugin ? If the author added this, it is for a reason. But I absolutely need to fire an event on click.

**My JS:**

```
$("body").on("click", "#likebox", function() {
alert('click');
});
```

or

```
$("body").on("click", ".thebutton", function() {
alert('click');
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="likebox">
<button class="thebutton"></div>
</div>
```

Also, when the button is clicked, this is the triggered event (Saw it in the JS files) : WordpressUlikeLoading

Maybe I could do something with this ?

Comment: You could define the event handler on the element itself after it was generated, a delegated event listener just won't work in this case as far as I can see.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I think the event.stopPropagation is just after the click and not the generation of the button

Comment: Then just do `$(".thebutton").click(function() { ... })` so you don't have to rely on the event propagating to `body`. I was assuming you used it because the button is dynamically added.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in your case, but you can try to deal with a “dead zone” creating new event binder after element creation, someting like:

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert("eeeeee");
}, true);
```

```js
// find element
var banner = $("#banner-message");

function changeColor() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    banner.removeClass("alt");
    alert('Your function');
  }, 1000)
}

// simulating async creation of element
var button = $("<button>", {
  text: "Change color",
  id: "add"
}).on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  banner.addClass("alt");
  alert('button click');
}).appendTo(banner);



document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  changeColor()
}, true);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Another aproach *(We can call this as ["quick fix", "workaround", "gambiarra", "Macgyver"])*. But can work to you, is to bind your event to a parent overlaid element by CSS, and after, trigger original event. Something like:

```js
// find element
    var banner = $("#banner-message");
    
    $(document).on('click', "#overlay-example", function(e) {
     changeColor();
      $(this).find('button#add').click();
    });

    function changeColor() {
      banner.removeClass("alt");
      alert('Your function');
    }

    // simulating async creation of element
    var button = $("<button>", {
      text: "Change color",
      id: "add"
    }).on("click", function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      banner.addClass("alt");
      alert('button click');
    }).appendTo(banner.find('#overlay-example'));
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

/* */
#banner-message #overlay-example {
  z-index: 10;
}

#banner-message #overlay-example #add {
  z-index: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <div id="overlay-example">
  
  </div>
</div>
```